# rename files to concatenation of path

Tags: bash, shell, file

```bash
find "inputscan" -type f -exec sh -c 'file="$1"; folder=$(basename $(dirname "$file")); filename=$(basename "$file"); cp "$file" "$2/$folder"_"$filename"' sh {} "staging" \;
```

If there are five files in `input_scan` like:

```
/inputscan
 /folder1
  /1.txt
   /folder2
    /2.txt
 /folder3
  /3.txt
4.txt
```

The file names once moved to staging should look like:

```
inputscan_folder1_1.txt
inputscan_folder1_folder2_2.txt
inputscan_folder3_3.txt
inputscan_4.txt
```

Currently, I am getting `folder1_1.txt,folder2_2.txt,folder3_3.txt,inputscan_4.txt` with the above commands.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/030 (How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
find inputscan -type f -exec bash -c '
for src; do
  dest=staging/${src//\//_}
  echo mv "$src" "$dest"
done' bash {} +
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [realpath](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html).
It's shows the entire file path.
From this data you can easily able to cut out the not necessary parts and copy or move the file.

```
$ realpath example.txt
  /home/username/example.txt
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please provide a solution that solves the user case because they might no have the necessary knowledge to apply the information you provided.